# How can i fetch a field from a specific only

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have this simple data in Firebase Realtime Database:

[image: secreenshot]

Now i need to fetch data by using this code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
          shrinkWrap: true,

          query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference(),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,Animation<double> animation,  int index) {
            return Text(snapshot.value["name"]);
          },),
      ),
    );
  }
```

With this code i will get two fields fetched in UI which are [name : Andy] and [name:Derek]

for more explain i screenshot this data

[image: secreenshoot]

but How could i fetch only one field? Let's say i need to fetch only [name : Andy] which is under User 1 child.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("User 1");
```

This will return the `User 1` object

Comment: i tried this it gives error which says Class bool has no instance methood [] reciver true trird calling [] ("name ")

Comment: @AslanMahy try `Text(snapshot.value.toString())` and tell me what do you get

Comment: yes its work but it fetch all fields under user 1 .. activity field + name .. do i can fetch name only ? .. and thanks so mush

Comment: Sure, you can use `child("User 1/name")` to get only the user's name.

Comment: if you meant like this FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("User 1/name")
..... 
Text(snapshot.value.toString())

nothing been fetch .. empty secreen